# ES6 A class that extends another class that is imported dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, webpack, es6-class

I use webpack to bundle my es6 code, my libraries have gotten quite large and so I looked into webpack dynamic import to split my libraries.

I understand the concept and it works quite well, but now I am faced with an issue where I want to create a Backbone view that extends from Backbone.View. I want to load Backbone only when it is required.

I got something like this.

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "backbone" */ 'backbone').then(Backbone =>{
    class MyView extends Backbone.View{
        //here I do some awesomeness
    }
});
export {MyView}
```

I keep getting an error that MyView cannot be found/ was not defined and cannot be exported.

Most likely I am doing this whole this wrong, but any direction would be really helpful.

Comment: MyView won't be defined for the export as it's only defined within the scope of the ```then```

Comment: *Why* are you dynamically importing backbone here? There doesn't seem to be a reason not to make it static.

Comment: The best thing you could do is export the promise for the class.

Comment: @Bergi Its not about backbone specifically but more the concept of how to achieve this, or if there is a way to achieve correctly.
If I export the promise, then how would my import look?

import MyView from 'MyView'
Or would this need to use import() as it supports the promise interface?

Comment: @Beyerz You would do something like `import MyViewPromise from '…'; MyViewPromise.then(MyView => { … });`. It would be quite similar to `import('…').then(MyView => { … });`, yes.

Comment: @Bergi, that makes sense, however then the entire system is forced in a promise-style coding. Thinking of this on a larger scale, each import essentially triggers import dependencies that can run really deep. Do you see any difficulty in debugging such systems?

Comment: Yes, dynamic imports force asynchrony on everything. It's a good reason to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something more like :

```
import * from 'backbone';

class MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //here I do some awesomeness
});

export MyView;
```

In your example `MyView` is declared in a different scope than the `export`.

Comment: Maybe I missed something here, but how does this resolve the load on demand concept?

Comment: It fixed the other problem `I keep getting an error that MyView cannot be found/ was not defined and cannot be exported.` but true like this backbone will be load not dynamically.

Comment: I think I'm just not understanding how Webpack manages loading chunks on demand.
Thanks though, I appreciate the feedback